# Can I quit claim deed my property to anyone I want?

Tags: real-estate

I would like to transfer my property to a random person I do not know by quit claim deed. Can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You will probably need the person's full name and address. You will probably need to pay a notary fee, and possibly a registration fee at whatever government office handles land titles in your jurisdiction. The recipient might chose to decline.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a small problem complying with local law (e.g. [RCW 64.04.050](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=64.04&full=true#64.04.050)), if the deed is required to have a "consideration" clause. If the grantee gives you something in return, you're okay. The typical "love and affection" clause would be untrue in such a case. This is not insurmountable.